# Как подключить внешний "класс" в pascal

Tags: функции, pascal

Понятно, что в паскале нет ООП.
Но не знаю как это еще можно назвать. Библиотека что-ли.
Нужно что-то типа

```
import myClass;  {внутри myClassProcedure и myClassFunction}
 ...  
myClassProcedure(x, y);  
result = myClassFunction(col, row);
```

Зачем? Хочу вставить туда частоиспользуемые функции и не писать их каждый раз.
То есть содержимое файла myClass - это набор функций и процедур.
Надеюсь, это вообще возможно?

Comment: >Понятно, что в паскале нет ООП 

эмм..c чего вы взяли? Даже в такой древней реализации, как TurboPascal ООП есть аж с 1989 года.

Что касается вашего вопроса, то погуглите по словам **uses** и **unit**

Comment: @DreamChild ну трупный паскаль -- это не совсем паскаль, это паскаль с объедками, так что в какой-то мере @samoilow и прав, но unit и uses -- это совсем не ООП. Это система модулей, заимствованная, кажется, из modula-2.

А объедки в TP появились вроде с TP5

Comment: @DreamChild unit и uses - это как раз то, что нужно, спасибо. Сейчас напишу сюда синтаксис для потомков. :)

Comment: @alexlz во-первых, в моей фразе про ТрубоПаскаль ключевым словом было **"даже"**. Тем самым я хотел сказать, что сейчас по-моему в любой более-менее современной реализации есть ООП (стандарт объектно-ориентированного Паскаля вышел в 1993 году)
Во-вторых, ТС не говорил, что эта "библиотека"должна быть реализована  именно средствами ООП, да и я нигде не утверждал, что uses и unit - это ООП

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мои цели -  создание набора функций и процедур - решается таким образом:
1) Создается файл имя_файла.pas

```
unit <идентификатор>;   {/* идентификатор == имя_файла */}
interface
{/* открытые описания */}

implementation
{/* закрытые описания процедуры и функции */}

begin
{/* код инициализации */}
end.
```

Пример реализации:

```
unit intLib;
   interface
      function max(i, j: integer): integer;

   implementation

      function max;
      begin
         if (i > j) then max:=i else max:=j;
      end;

end.
```

Пример использования:

```
uses intLib;
var a, b: integer;
begin
   write('Введите числа: ');
   readln(a, b);
   writeln('Максимальное значение равно ', max(a, b));
   readln;
end.
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, и хочется именно библиотеки (отдельной dll) которую можно использовать в разных приложениях, то стоит глянуть ещё в сторону слова library.